# Django - Inline formset and many-to-many relationship

Tags: django, forms, many-to-many, inline-formset

So I have 2 models: Team and Member. I have a pivot table called MemberTeam.

Here is my MemberTeam model:

```
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    team = models.ForeignKey('acpkinballmanageteams.Team',verbose_name=_("team"))
    role = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=ROLE_CHOICES,verbose_name=_("role"),blank=False,default='player')
```

So when an admin creates a team, I wanted for them to add the players directly. So I created an inlineformset. Here is my MemberTeamForm:

```
class MemberTeamForm(forms.ModelForm):

    member = AutoCompleteSelectField(lookup_class=MemberLookup2,required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MemberTeam
```

Nothing to fancy. And here is how I created the formsets:

```
TeamRosterFormset = inlineformset_factory(Team, MemberTeam, fields=('member','role'), \
form=MemberTeamForm,can_delete=True, extra=1, max_num=18)
```

Everything works fine if I create a team and add no members. It also works fine if I add/edit/remove members from the team edit page. The problem is when I try to add a team with a member, I get this error:
"" needs to have a value for field "team" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Here is the view that is being used (It's a Create-form based view):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    teamroster_formset = cp_forms.TeamRosterFormset(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)

    if teamroster_formset.is_valid():
        teamroster_formset.instance = self.object
        teamroster_formset.save()
```

I have no idea what is going and what I should do... Any ideas please?

Thanks,
Ara

Answer (score 1):

Well dumb me... Just had to remove the commit=false from the .save() method -.-